# Java: Accessing subclass methods from objects in arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am trying to access methods in the class Car from my arraylist. The class hierarchy is essentially:

```java
class Vehicle {} 
class Car extends Vehicle {} 
class Chevy extends Car {}
class Ford extends Car {}
```

In this example `Car` class has a getter called `getID()`

The `main` method looks like this:

```java
Ford vehicle1 = new Ford(id, model, etc);
Chevy vehicle2 = new Chevy(id, model, etc);

ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
list.add(vehicle1);
list.add(vehicle2);
```

Through a lot of trial an error I've been able to access the getID() method like so:

```java
System.out.println("Vehicle ID: " + ((Chevy) list.get(1)).getID());
```

Which works... I just can't imagine I'm doing this the proper way. Is there a better way to access these sub class methods?

Answer (score 0):

For a serious program, your `Vechicle` interface should define all the behavioral methods common to all vehicles, which should include your `getID()` method. However, in some cases you might want to have specific method that *only* applies to a certain type of vehicles; then you need to either do that in subclasses or sub interfaces to `Vehicle`. Take your above example, you might want to have a `NamedVehicle` with that `getID()` method. How to arrange your interfaces and classes is up to you. Refer to **bridge** design pattern if that helps.

Having said the above, in very occasional places you do want to do the explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a subclass objects in the list seems fine, but u would never know which child object would be accessed when iterating over the list.

I would suggest you could have parent reference point to child object in the following way.

```
Car vehicle1 = new Ford(id, model, etc);
Car vehicle2 = new Chevy(id, model, etc);
```

And add then to list as seen.
When you iterate over the list u would downcast it based on the instanceof check, which would make it more conventional.

ex:

```
Car c = (Car)list.get(0)).getID();
if(c instanceof Ford){

    Ford f = (Ford)c;
    System.out.println(f.getId());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why vehicle isn't an interface (classes cannot extend interfaces, they implement it)?

As far as I understood `Vehicle` doesn't have a `getId()` while `Car` does, that's why not casting your `Vehicle` array list object to a subclass which has such method (like `Chevy`) causes an error.

If you did:

```
System.out.println("Vehicle ID: " + ((Car) list.get(1)).getID());
```

it would have worked.

I suggest you to make `Vehicle` an interface:

```
interface Vehicle{
    public int getId();
}

class Car implements Vehicle{ //altough I think this also should be abstract
    int id;

    @Override
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

With this configuration you can do:

```
Car vehicle1 = new Ford(id, model, etc);
Car vehicle2 = new Chevy(id, model, etc);

ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
list.add(vehicle1);
list.add(vehicle2);

System.out.println("Vehicle ID: " + list.get(1).getID()); //Chevy ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `getId()` method is declared in the `Car` class, then you can only access this method through inheritance (**of cource need to be marked with either of access modifiers `protected` or `public`**).

So any subclass of `Car` will have access to the `getId()` method and should have the behavior marked in the `Car#getId` unless that method is **overriden** in the related subtype thus at runtime the method behavior will be evaluted based on the current object type and not the object reference.

Now coming to one of the most famous OO (Object Oriented) features which is **polymorphism** (many forms) which let you pass any `Car` subtype where a car is needed, and return any `Car` subtype when you expect a `Car` instance.

So to sumup, you can have any `Car` subtype in an `ArrayList` of `Car`(s): `Ford`, `Chevy` and you will be able then to call any `Car` instance method on any item of the list (whatever real type it is, it does not matter since it is a child of `Car`).

The main issue now is that the described behavior can't go in the other side, so a **parent reference** (in you case `Vehicle`) would never know about its descendants behavior (the `Car` in your case) unless an explicit cast is met under the road.

Then you will need simply put, to instantiante your `ArrayList` using the `Car` as a Generic type (that's what you are doing when you say `<Vehicle>`, `<Car>`):

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Ford vehicle1 = new Ford(id, model, etc);
  Chevy vehicle2 = new Chevy(id, model, etc);

  ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>(); //Use a Car as generic type so you can call all car methods
  list.add(vehicle1);
  list.add(vehicle2);

  for(Car car : list)
  {
    System.out.println(car.getId()); // Iterate over the list and retrieve each element ID
  }
}
```